# PyCharm: debugging Django shell in a standard terminal window

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am using PyCharm to debug django code in the shell as suggested in [this post](http://hirelofty.com/blog/configuring-pycharm-debug-django-shell/). However, I miss being able to use ctrl+r and vertical arrows to quickly recall previous commands like one can do when running *manage.py shell* in standard terminal (for me, it's Gnome Terminal on Ubuntu).

Is there a way to attach the PyCharm debugger to a *manage.py shell* session running in a standard terminal window?

Comment: If you want to run it in the shell, I don't see why you want to get PyCharm involved at all. Just do `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in the code where you want the breakpoint, and run the server from the terminal.

Comment: I just like the PyCharm debugger interface more.